# including .eps with Texmaker

Tags: eps, epstopdf

I know this question appears on a lot of pages already, however the common answers don't solve my problem.

When I try to include `.eps`-files into my document I get the all known error:

> **! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...graphics{pics/file.eps}**

This is a common error when using `\usepackage{graphicx}` and the solution should be to use `\usepackage{epstopdf}` right with it.

However i still get an error :(.

I'm using the newest versions of MikTex and Texmaker. I'd appreciate any suggestions! :)

Comment: You may have to include `\graphicspath{{pics}}` in your preamble.

Comment: In addition to the @Werner suggestion, be aware to compile with `latex` instead `pdflatex` for use `.eps` files, otherwise the error remains.

Comment: @Aradnix: with modern compilers, this conversion _should_ be automatic (hence the OP's question).

Comment: Remove the extension .eps.

Comment: @Werner Which compilers can achieve that?

Comment: @Aradnix: `pdflatex`

Comment: hey thank you all for the fast replies! @Werner: unfortunately this showed no improvement :(

Comment: @Aradnix: i heard of that one before, however i don't really know how to handle it. I'm using the german version of Texmaker with the standard option that translates to something like: fast translating. I can chose Latex in the same dropdown but get a lot of errors when compiling. any suggestion?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can remove the .eps-extension either in the code or in the name of the actual file. in the first case I get ! LaTeX Error: File `pics/grenzschichtaufloesung' not found.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...=1\textwidth]{pics/grenzschichtaufloesung}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer in the second case I get the unknown graphic extension error message

Comment: You should naturally remove the extension (and the dot) in the code. If this doesn't work then probably epstopdf wasn't able to convert the eps to pdf. Do you have perl installed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer when i remove the file extension from the code, texmaker can't find the file anymore. this is also the case for any other graphic file, e.g. .png

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i haven't installed anything in addition to miktex and texmaker, so I assume perl isn't installed. Does epstopdf need that to work? if so, what kind of installation would that be? something within my compiler or totally independent from it on my pc?

Comment: I don't know if you need perl nowadays (the original script is a perl script, but the binary can be selfcontained). I do have perl installed and so it is difficult to test what happens if don't have it. You could try to convert the eps with `epstopdf file.eps` on the command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer alright, I converted the .eps to a .pdf using "epstopdf file.eps" on the command line. Then I included the .pdf into my document and it works just fine :) I tried other tools to convert the .eps to .pdf before but they where much slower and never matched my expectations. Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: Well, according to @Werner you can get it using `pdflatex` as I think you do with `TeXmaker`, but how I don't know. When I have to use `.eps` I simply change to `latex` as compiler instead `pdflatex` and that's all. In the other hand is very hard to help you without a MWE that show us what are you doing.

Comment: @Sebastiano Each time you make such an unnecessary edit to an old question you push a contemporary question off the front page and bereave it from its well deserved attention. It will be your fault if an user does not get an answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano May I also remind you of a conversation that happened less than a month ago? https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49249184#49249184  Block quotes are no suitable markup for log file excerpts because they don't conserve line breaks.